# How to stop listening to all events of contract

Tags: truffle, javascript, events

I am using the JavaScript API in my truffle tests to get the events from the contract:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-allevents

```
          const allEvents = instance.allEvents({
            fromBlock: 0,
            toBlock: 'latest'
          });
          allEvents.watch((err, res) => {
            console.log(res);
          });
```

It never stops listening so I tried adding this to the end:

```
          allEvents.stopWatching()
```

The listening stops, but nothing is ever logged, so I tried adding a delay:

```
          setTimeout(allEvents.stopWatching, 1000);
```

But the listening doesn't stop.

How do I stop listening after all the events emitted till now have been retrieved?

Comment: What version of web3 are you using? Which condition should cause to stop watching all events? If you call `.stopWatching()` immediately after `.watch()` it will stop there before any event, setTimeout might not work because `allEvents.stopWatching` is a function without a binding.

Comment: web3 Version '0.20.6' included in Truffle.
The condition that should cause it to stop watching is that it got all the past events, but I don't know how to identify that.

Answer (score 2):

1) Using Indexed parameters e.g address or integers can also be very useful

**Examplen using ERC20.sol**[check here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol)
`Erc20.transfer` should emit `event(address _to, uint256 _amount)` which can be indexed  thus making it easier to filter at the front end
 `event Transfer(address indexed _to, uint256 _amount);`    [contract events](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events)

could be written this way, and you get events only from the indexed address and indexed amount during transfer.

```
Erc20.events.Transfer({ filter: { _to: recipient, _amount: amount} })
        .on("data", function(event) {
....
        }).on("error", console.error);
      }
```

I hope someone finds this helpful, I'm also open to correction.

Answer (score 1):

It says that if you pass a callback function you don't need to call stopWatching(). The problem is somewhere else so just abandon the idea of using stopWatching. 
Could you try this implementation instead:

```
const allEvents = instance.allEvents({
        fromBlock: 0,
        toBlock: 'latest'
      });
      allEvents.watch((err, res) => {
        if (!error)
        console.log(res);
      });
```

Give me an update

Comment: Same as before, doesn't stop listening